# Terraform policy import errors

Tags: terraform, hashicorp-vault, vault

I have a bunch of existing Vault policies with the following naming conventions

- org1.bu1
- org1.bu2
- ....
- org1.buN

I would like to manage these policies using terraform, however when I try to import these vault policies using terraform

```
terraform import vault_policy.org1.bu1 org1.bu1
```

I get the following error

```
Error: Invalid address
│
│   on <import-address> line 1:
│    1: vault_policy.org1.bu1
│
│ Resource instance key must be given in square brackets.
```

Comment: Please add an example `vault_policy` resource to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the vault_policy resource that I had and which caused the issue.

```
resource "vault_policy" "org1.bu1" {
  name   = "org1.bu1"
  ....
}
```

I then changed it to

```
resource "vault_policy" "org1_bu1" {
  name   = "org1.bu1"
  ....
}
```

```
terraform import vault_policy.org1_bu1 org1.bu1
```

And this fixed the issue and enabled me to import the existing policy